# What does "Current Detection" feature mean in KNX actuators?

Tags: home-automation

I understand that KNX/EIB actuators are used to switch on/off lights in fancier homes.  Some of these actuators have "**current detection**" feature, and some do not.

What can that feature do?

Is it for systems where you may want to know much power each circuit is consumes?  Or is it a safety/protection thing?

This question should be tagged KNX/EIB, but these tags don't exist.

Examples:
https://library.e.abb.com/public/cfaa4977bc174ddaa7c6da77c9f46ce0/Technical%20Data%20SAS%20x1661.pdf

http://gvshome.com/product/gvs-kbus-switch-actuator-8-foldwith-current-detector/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have 10 lights in parallel that each draw 1A, for a total of 10A load. Now, suppose a light burns out. Your load current drops to 9A. If you implement current detection in the controller, the controller could turn around and alert someone that a light on that particular circuit is out.

Comment: Thanks, the actuator is able to tell the main controller the current drawn, and the alert functionality would be in the software of the main controller right?

Comment: Yep, all the logic goes in the main controller.